# Java: Classes and Extended Classes

Tags: java, class, oop, extends, superclass

Suppose I have a class called `A`. I have another class that extends `A` called `B`.

`B` contains a method called `BsMethod()` that `A` does not contain.

Say I declare an array of `A`: `arrA = new A[10]`

And I assign `arrA[1] = new B();`

And I try to call `BsMethod` by doing `arrA[1].BsMethod()`

This gives an error saying that `arrA` does not contain this method. What should I change so that I can call `BsMethod` using `arrA[1]`?

Answer (score 2):

This is failing because at the compile java compiler is not able to bind the method with `class A` object, it can not find the method `BsMethod()` in `class A`.

You can cast the object to `class B` and use it.

```
((B)arrA[1]).BsMethod();
```

In the **Dynamic Binding** the actual method call are determined at the run time. So if you have a method in super class and you also override it in the sub class. Then the actual method call, for such method, is determined at the runtime.

You can read more about static and dynamic binding here with example. [`Static Binding and Dynamic Binding`](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding)

Comment: That's not really accurate; the binding is still dynamic, and the JVM will still determine at runtime which method to actually call (since it could be overridden).  Static binding only occurs when overriding is impossible, meaning a static, final or private method.  But it's true that (without casting) the compile-time type of `arrA[1]` is `A`, so the compiler can not bind on the method declared in `B`.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I hope this make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `arrA[1]` as `B` since `arrA` is an array of `A` and the compiler doesn't know about `B` at this point.

Call it like this: `((B)arrA[1]).BsMethod()`